# Interaction of a hashable class with Enum in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, hash, enums, magic-methods

I have defined a class which I am trying to make hashable. Additionally, there's an enum which uses objects of this class as values of its enum members.

```
from enum import Enum


class Dummy(object):
    def __init__(self, name, property_):
        self.name = name             # can only be a string
        self.property = property_    # can only be a string

    def __hash__(self):
        # print "Hash called for ", self
        # print("----")
        return hash(self.property)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        # print "Eq called for: "
        # print self
        # print other
        return (self.property == other.property)

    def __ne__ (self, other):
        return not (self == other)

    def __str__(self):
        return (self.name + "$" + self.property)


class Property(Enum):
    cool = Dummy("foo", "cool")
    hot = Dummy("bar", "hot")
```

Although this works fine, I noticed -- by un-commenting the `print` statements -- that the `__hash__` and `__eq__` magic methods are invoked for the two enum member values. Why is this so? Aren't these used only during hashing and equality checks?

Additionally, if I change the enum class to the following, all hell breaks loose.

```
class Property(Enum):
    cool = Dummy("foo", "cool")
    hot = [Dummy("bar-1", "hot-1"), Dummy("bar-2", "hot-2")]
```

The `__eq__` magic method seems to be called for the `Dummy` object corresponding to `Property.cool` and the list corresponding to `Property.hot`, as evident from the output:

```
Hash called for  foo$cool
----
Eq called for: 
foo$cool
[<__main__.Dummy object at 0x7fd36633f2d0>, <__main__.Dummy object at 0x7fd36633f310>]
----
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 28, in <module>
    class Property(Enum):
  File "/blah/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/enum/__init__.py", line 237, in __new__
    if canonical_member.value == enum_member._value_:
  File "test.py", line 19, in __eq__
    return (self.property is other.property)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'property'
```

Why is this happening? Why are the magic methods called in the first place, and why is `__eq__` called on a class object and a list?

Please note that this is only a representative example, and the real use-case makes this design -- enum with values as lists of hashable class objects -- appear less weird.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Enum class is comparing its member object values to see if any are aliases of another. For example, in the following Enum, both `a` and `b` represent the same value, so only `a` should show up in the member list (aliases don't):

```
class A(Enum):
    a=1
    b=1
```

You can verify this by looking at the source code for the line that did the equality check: [source](https://bitbucket.org/stoneleaf/enum34/src/f24487b45cd041fc9406d67441d2186ac70772b7/enum/__init__.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#__init__.py-237)

For the hashing, this is done to provide a by-value lookup of the enum members. Again, this can be found in the [source code](https://bitbucket.org/stoneleaf/enum34/src/f24487b45cd041fc9406d67441d2186ac70772b7/enum/__init__.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#__init__.py-253)

Comment: This answers everything; thanks. So, values of enum members cannot be a mutable object, like a list, which is not hashable.

Comment: They can be. If the value isn't hashable, it will only not be included in the by-value lookup table, so trying to find it by value will loop through the members and check for equality instead